# The PIE root *per- "forward, through" : How did it evolve to mean 'private' ?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

> [[Etymonline :]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=private&allowed_in_frame=0) ... privus "one's own, individual," from PIE *prei-wo-, from PIE *prai-, *prei-, from root *per- (1) **"forward, through"** (see [per](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=per&allowed_in_frame=0)).  ...
>
> [[AHI :]](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#IR123200) per<sup>1</sup> ...
> ... from Latin prīvus, single, alone (< "standing in front," "isolated from others");

I'm confused because someone, who's **"forward, through"**, sounds open and overt. But this appearance is contradicted by the evolution from the PIE root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dictionary does not give "prei" but gives ***prea̯i***, a prepositional adverb. It is formed by adding the locative ending -i, in a similar way like other prepositional adverbs are formed: ***a̯enti***, ***ndheri***, ***medhi***. It meant "in the front, before", but also could mean "near, at" (consider for instance its Russian derivative "pri" "near, at").

So something like ***prea̯iu̯os*** logically would mean "the thing at/near somebody".

Comment: Thanks. Would you please tell me which dictionary or dictionaries you're using?

Comment: @Law Area 51 Proposal - Commit You can check this reference for instance: http://www.phil.muni.cz/linguistica/art/blazek/bla-001.pdf

Answer (score 1):

What's unclear about the derivation given in AHI? "Forward" yields "standing in front, isolated from others," which in turn yields "single, alone." From that it is a natural evolution to "something kept for oneself alone and not shared with others."

Comment: AHI was unclear to me because I don't understand or didn't perceive that ` "Forward" yields "standing in front, isolated from others,"`. Does this answer your question?